# How to Get Bookmarks on the Left Pane?

Tags: bookmarks

I have seen several PDF documents which, when opened in adobe acrobat, gives bookmarks to every chapter, section and subsection in the left pane. Is there any easy way to generate such PDF files with LaTeX? I have an about 100 page document in `report` class. How do I modify the code to get bookmarks like that?

Comment: Have a look at [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or [bookmark](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark).

Comment: Basically, just loading `\usepackage{hyperref}` as the last package before `\begin{document}` should do the job. And you should use `pdflatex`, not `latex+dvips+pspdf` or `latex+dvipdfm`.

Answer (score 4):

The `hyperref` package with option `bookmarksopen=true` can achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % random texts
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksopen=true}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Better to load `hyperref` *last* in your preamble.

Comment: thanks a lot. Any way to remove the red boxes around the text, even though I know they don't appear on the printout. I am not sure whether it is just because of my university document class or something else.

Comment: @Barman: Use option `colorlinks`, and use `linkcolor=..., citecolor=..., urlcolor=...` to set colors of various links.